# I am getting error in sails-hook-cron npm package in sail js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, sails.js

I am trying to use the sails-hook-cron npm package.I have install this npm package with 3.2.0 version but when I run the application through sails lift then I am getting following error.
The bootstrap function encountered an error *AFTER* calling its callback!  Details: Error: Unknown alias: y
at H:..\node_modules\cron\lib\cron.js:409:11